# In the recent years

Tags: grammar

**Despite many things we improved, in the recent years many projects failed.**

Where to place "in the recent years" correctly?

Comment: Remove *the*. Just *in recent years*.

Comment: Things were improved in recent years or many things were improved perhaps a long time ago but in recent years projects failed?

Comment: Despite/in spite of many improvements in recent years, many projects (still) failed. However, to keep the already long sentence short, despite is what i would use.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that. His question is about placement of the phrase in the sentence, not the words in the phrase itself.

Comment: @Barmar That thread gives the answer to OP's query 'Where to place "in the recent years" correctly?' The expression is not used by native English speakers. ' "In the recent years" is hardly found at all. Compared with "in recent years", Ngrams shows a flat line for its use. The British National Corpus has two records for it, against 2344 for "in recent years".' [Barrie England] This answers the necessary question behind the question. One could just close-vote on 'not a valid question' grounds, if you prefer?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Assuming he corrects the phrase to _in recent years_, this question still stands independent of that.

Comment: I don't tink he's asking where he should use this phrase instead of _in recent years_. He's asking where in the sentence such a phrase belongs. Modernizing the grammar of the phrase is a separate issue.

Comment: The sentence would be nearly unacceptable even if the 'the' were dropped. 'Despite the many improvements we have made in our methodology, in recent years, many projects have still failed' or 'Despite the many improvements we have made in our methodology, many projects have still failed in recent years' addresses most if not all points. Pedantry (using the 'correct' close-vote option) would not have helped OP at all (not pointing them to one unidiomatic usage). I prefer 'helpful' to 'pedantic'; don't you, @Barmar?